# Searching text using CONTAINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, contains

Using `CONTAINS`, I am searching for the word '`text\`' followed by any string:

```
select * from table1
where CONTAINS (availableText, 'TEXT\%')
```

However, this query returns hits where there is text before the '`TEXT`' string; for example, this is one false hit: '`there is no text available`'.

Looking for a way to just get the hits like '`TEXT\path\...`' and not '`dir\TEXT\path\..`'.

I know how to do this using `LIKE`, but would prefer `CONTAINS` instead.

Comment: according to the docs,  the CONTAINS keyword does not act the same as the LIKE keyword. It simply determines if the keyword string is included in the string to check. If it exists, it returns true. You most likely will need to use LIKE to check if it is at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this is possible using CONTAINS.
CONTAINS uses a full-text index internally (a structure that can be imagined like a big index of all the words for a set of texts). This is the reason why CONTAINS is significantly faster than LIKE for most cases because it can lookup your queried word(s) in the full-text index and retrieve the corresponding key(s) to the row(s) containing the text with that word(s).
LIKE scans all rows (if '%' is the beginning of your query) or at least an index on the queried column (if your query doesn't start with a wildcard character).

In your case I would advise to create an index on the (n)varchar column and use LIKE since you are doing prefix based searches.
If you definitely want to use CONTAINS you might want to use that operator first and then use LIKE on that restricted result set.